# How to append information from a list that is not in the current loop

Tags: python, list, append

I am searching for matchin entries in two lists and when i find a match i want to append some information from one list and some from another to a new list.

```
## Product list
ta_prod = []

prod = open("products.txt", "r")
for line2 in prod:
    row2 = line2.split(",")
    ta_prod.append(row2[4])


## Producs Ordered
supne = []
ta_prodord = []
prodord = open("products_ordered.txt", "r")
for line in prodord:
    row = line.split(",")
    prodordnavn = re.sub('"',"",row[1])
    ta_prodord.append(prodordnavn)
    if prodordnavn in ta_prod:
        supne.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],row2[11]])
```

My problem is with the "row2[11]" argument. It gives the same entry everytime, and not the entry linked with the match.

To be clear, where i write "row2[11]" i want to append the entry in collumn 11 (counting from 0) that is on the same row as the match found just above.

Comment: There isn't any link here. Why do you think there is one? You haven't provided any way of linking `row` with `row2`. How is Python supposed to know what makes it the "same row"?

Comment: I don't expect python to know. i expected my coding to be wrong and that's why i'm here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `row2` variable holds the last row2 from the first loop.

You can use a dictionary to save the needed row2[11] values:

```
## Product list
ta_prod = {} # dictionary instead of list

prod = open("products.txt", "r")
for line2 in prod:
    row2 = line2.split(",")
    prodordnavn = row2[4] # reading the referencing key
    ta_prod[prodordnavn] = row2[11] # the value you would like to use in the other loop


## Producs Ordered
supne = []
ta_prodord = []
prodord = open("products_ordered.txt", "r")
for line in prodord:
    row = line.split(",")
    prodordnavn = re.sub('"',"",row[1])
    ta_prodord.append(prodordnavn)
    if prodordnavn in ta_prod:
        value = ta_prod[prodordnavn] # reading the value from ta_prod dictionary by prodordnavn key
        supne.append([row[0],row[1],row[2],value])
```